# What's happened to system images in Android SDK downloads?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-studio

I'm trying to set up an emulator in Android - but can't as there is no system image available fro my device (Nexus 7 (2012).  Tried to get this by updating the SDK, but there is no  option to select "ARM EABi System Image".

This is the case both with Eclipse and Android Studio - what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Android SDK tools 19 & 20  Allocates lots of Ram memory especially if you go with nexus 7 it consists of 1900 MB Ram so your eclipse might not have supported with that high ram so it cause these sorts of problems and it wont show your system image.

so you have to update android SDK Tools 23 that's the only choice and set emulator nexus 7 or nexus 5 or Nexus one with 512 MB Ram it will work

**NOTE :** if you install update 23 it will directly assign to android wear system image where you have to change to Nexus 7 or Nexus one .

According to me the best i could prefer is Nexus one, its better to create a Emulator with Nexus one because it runs all sorts of API Levels

Comment: I have sdk manager rev 23.0.2.  However. I did find in my /sdk/add-ons folder a whole set of /addon-google_apis-google-(rev) folders, which contained an image folder holding the armeabi-v7a stuff - i copied these to a folder/sdk/system-images and seem to be upand running.